# Deleting from array via object

Tags: swift

I have a protocol "Visual" which is implemented by two classes : Point2D and Square

```
protocol Visual {
    var text: String { get }

}


class Point2D : Visual {
  var text: String 
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    init(x : Double , y : Double)
    {
      self.x = x 
      self.y = y
      self.text = "I'm 2d point"
      }
}

class Square : Visual {
  var text: String 
    var x: Int

    init(x : Int)
    {
      self.x = x 
      self.text = "I'm square"
     }
}
```

I have made a class Storage which will keep in array the elements and has two operations add and delete

```
class Storage
{
  var elements : [Visual]

  init()
  {
    elements = [Visual]()
  }

  func add(item : Visual)
  {
    elements.append(item)

  }
  func delete(item : Visual)
  {

  }

  func printItems()
  {
    print(elements)
  }
}
```

The add works fine , but how should I implement the delete since I pass object with refrence to "Visual".I want to delete the first seen object from left to right ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete the first item that matches? Or what do you mean with "left to right"?

Comment: if there are duplicates of the object to delete in the array , I want to remove the first one seen when iterating from the start of the array until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a way to evaluate the equality of them. I would suggest something like this. (I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/59818098/2907715) about equality on protocol very helpful.)

```swift
protocol Visual {
    var text: String { get }
    func isEqual(to other: Visual) -> Bool
}

extension Point2D {
    func isEqual(to other: Visual) -> Bool {
        return (other as? Self).flatMap({ $0.x == self.x && $0.y == self.y }) ?? false
    }
}

extension Square {
    func isEqual(to other: Visual) -> Bool {
        return (other as? Self).flatMap({ $0.x == self.x }) ?? false
    }
}
```

You can then find the first index of the item you want to delete and remove it using the returned index.

```swift
class Storage {

    // ...

    func delete(item : Visual) {
        if let index = elements.firstIndex(where: { $0.isEqual(to: item) }) {
            elements.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Equatable protocol when you declare Visual protocol, in this way you will be enable to compare object and to understand which are equals and they have to be removed.